# Not able to Upload large datasets(>10MB) in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dataset

I am trying to create a tool using R shiny but I am unable to upload large datasets(>10MB) as the load time is increasing and after few minutes the tool crashes. I have also included the option to increase the file size limit of the dataset. Can someone please help me with this query?

The tool is working for smaller datasets which are less than 10 MB.

Sample datasets:

1. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arianazmoudeh/airbnbopendata
2. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nurudeenabdulsalaam/fitbit-fitness-tracker-data

Below are few laptop as well as R version specifications:

**' Laptop Specifications: '**

Windows 10
System-
Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11850H @2.50GHz 2.50 GHz
Installed Memory (RAM): 16.0 GB(15.7GB usable)
System type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

**' R Studio Specification: '**

RStudio 2022.07.1+554 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (7872775ebddc40635780ca1ed238934c3345c5de, 2022-07-22) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

**app.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ff)
library(iotools)
library(readxl)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboard)

#UI Code
ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demo: Upload Large Dataset > 10 Mb"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("selectfile")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      withSpinner(tableOutput("tb1"),type = 6, color = "#0dc5c1")
      
    )
    
  )
))

#Server Code
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)

dashboard<- read.csv("dataset1.csv")
  
#Display the dataset in the renderTable format 
  output$tb1 <- renderTable({
    dashboard
  })
  
})

#Run App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When you say "upload", it suggests that you are running the app on a server and sending the data to the server while the app is running. Is that the case? Or are you running the app locally and having it read a local file to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following small edits the Shiny app works.

Major problem is the `renderTable` / `tableOutput` table format, which puts all data on the screen at once, which is never happening with so much data. You can test with smaller data set (like `iris`) to see. Switching to `DT::renderDataTable` / `DT::dataTableOutput` we can have pagination and fast response.  https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html

Tested moving the loading of data to the top of the application; and this did not matter.

Moved the `options` command to the top per https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html

Switched to `fread` "fast read" the csv, though that was the not the problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
#library(ff)
#library(iotools)
library(readxl)
#library(shinycssloaders)
#library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)
#dashboard<- fread("/home/username/Downloads/Airbnb_Open_Data.csv") #testing at the top
#dashboard<-iris  ##A test with only iris data

#UI Code
ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demo: Upload Large Dataset > 10 Mb"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("selectfile")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      #withSpinner(tableOutput("tb1"),type = 6, color = "#0dc5c1")
      #tableOutput("tb1")  #simple test without spinner
      DT::dataTableOutput("tb1")
    )
    
  )
))

#Server Code
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  #dashboard<- read.csv("/home/username/Downloads/Airbnb_Open_Data.csv")
      dashboard<- fread("/home/username/Downloads/Airbnb_Open_Data.csv")

  #Display the dataset in the renderTable format 
#  output$tb1 <- renderTable({
   output$tb1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      dashboard %>% select(-house_rules)
  })
})

#Run App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for the resolution. This really helped me. I have a one more doubt down the same road.
My aim: My aim is to read larger files >10gb efficiently using reactive function as the output of input file needs to fed into other reactive function.
fread not working instead reactive file upload function